# Derived distribution when function is not bijective

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Consider a random variable $X$ with PDF $f_X$. Find the PDF of $Y=X^2$

The well known formula for this is $$f_Y(y)=\bigg|\frac{d}{dy}(g^{-1}(y))\bigg|f_X(g^{-1}(y))$$

How do we plug in an appropriate $g^{-1}(y)$ value? Intuition says that it should be something of an average of the two branches of the inverse:

$$\frac{\frac{1}{2\sqrt y}f_X(\sqrt y)+\frac{1}{2\sqrt y}f_X(-\sqrt y)}2$$

but the (actual)answer obtained via finding CDF and differentiating is just the sum:

$$\frac{1}{2\sqrt y}f_X(\sqrt y)+\frac{1}{2\sqrt y}f_X(-\sqrt y)$$

What is going on here?

Comment: $X^2$ is in the vicinity of $y$ whenever $X$ is in the vicinity of either $\sqrt y$ OR $-\sqrt y$, so intuitively you should be adding probabilities, not averaging. The fact that there are two ways to get $y$ doesn't make those ways half as likely.

Comment: You just add all the terms at each inverse image of $y$. This is a consequence of the change of variables theorem for many to one functions, or even more general theorems for Lipschitz maps.